# Rails identification of leading zeroes when automatically converting a string to an integer in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leading-zero

I have a model in Rails which accepts an integer value. Sometimes it's submitted as a string with leading zeroes and I'd the option to output it as a string later with the leading zeroes.

I could store as a string in the db instead but I was wondering if there was another way. Simplified code below.

```
s = Speed.create(value: "03", measurement: "KPH")
expect(s.value).to eq(3)
expect(s.to_s).to eq("03KPH") # FAILS, returns "3KPH"
expect(s.padding).to eq(1) # FAILS, returns 0
```

I have a padding field in the database in which to store the number of leading zeroes.

Comment: Is `Speed` an active record model or a custom class? If it's custom, can you show the code?

Comment: This? `"%02d" % 3 #=> "03"`

Comment: @JonCairns, it's a standard ActiveRecord model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set/get your active record attributes by doing something like below,

```
class Speed < ActiveRecord::Base
  def value=(i)
    self.value = i 
  end 

  def value
    value.to_i
  end 
end
```

Comment: Not quite what I used in the end, but this answer was the most useful in coming up with a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep original information about the string, then store it as a string rather than an integer.  You can then add a method to translate it to an integer if needed, or just call "to_i" on it when you use it and want to use it as a number.

You could change your test to

```
s = Speed.create(value: "03", measurement: "KPH")
expect(s.value.to_i).to eq(3)
expect(s.to_s).to eq("03KPH") 
expect(s.padding).to eq(1)
```